# Making a number line, plotting the keys from a dictionary and then labeling them with the keys and making a legend

Tags: python, dictionary, matplotlib

I have a dictionary of keys (integers) and values (strings), I want to plot the keys on a number line. I want the highest value on the number line to be the highest key value and the lowest to be the lowest.

I then want to label each point with its key and color code or assign a certain shape to each point depending on what it's value is, then have a legend showing what value the color or shape relates to (Some of the values from the dictionary may be the same so thats why I want to color code).

This is the number line I have so far:

```
import matplotlib.pylab
Matches = {9: 'CCTA', 20: 'TGGA', 21: 'GGAC', 96: 'GGAC', 160: 'TGGA', 169: 'CCTA']
x,y = zip(*Matches)
zero = []
for i in x:
    zero.append(0)
plt.scatter(x,zero)
plt.show()
```

In summary I Just want help making a legend and labeling the points.

Sorry I am still trying to fully figure out matplotlib.

Thank you! Your help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Show us a sample dictionary so that we can give some solution. You have asked too many questions in one post without providing any data to reproduce the figure or provide a working solution

Comment: What is the purpose of the code you show?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for providing the sample dictionary in your question. Following is one way to plot what you want. Here you use the `keys` as the size for the markers as you asked for. The x-ticklabels are now your values. As you can see, two of them are overlapping because their keys are very close in magnitude.

I also used list comprehension to create `zero` list. You can also use NumPy's `np.zeros(len(x))` to create an array of 0's.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(8, 6))

Matches = {9: 'CCTA', 20: 'TGGA', 21: 'GGAC', 96: 'GGAC', 160: 'TGGA', 169: 'CCTA'}
x, y = zip(*Matches.items())
zero = [0 for i in x] 

plt.scatter(x,zero, s=x)
plt.xticks(x, y, rotation=45)
```

[image]